# How do I use numpy vectorize to iterate through a two-dimentional vector?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, vector, coordinates

I am trying to use numpy.vectorize to iterate over a (2x5) matrix which contains two vectors representing the x- and y-values of coordinates. The coordinates (x- and y-value) are to be fed to a function returning a (1x1) vector for each iteration. So that in the end, the result should be a (1x5) vector. My problem is that instead of iterating through each element I want the algorithm to iterate through both vectors simultaneously, so it picks up the x- and y-values of the coordinates in parallel to feed it to the function.

```
data = np.transpose(np.array([[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 1], [1, -1], [2, -1]]))
th_ = np.array([[1, 1]])
th0_ = -2

def positive(x, th = th_, th0 = th0_):
    if signed_dist(x, th, th0)[0][0] > 0:
        return np.array([[1]])
    elif signed_dist(x, th, th0)[0][0] == 0:
        return np.array([[0]])
    else:
        return np.array([[-1]])
positive_numpy = np.vectorize(positive)
results = positive_numpy(data)
```

Reading the numpy documentation did not really help and I want to avoid large workarounds in favor of computation timing. Thankful for any suggestion!

Comment: So did you see the disclaimer about computation time in the `np.vectorize` documentation?

Comment: Show us what you want to do with plain Python iteration.  `np.vectorize` does not help with speed.  It can help with broadcasting, but you aren't doing that here.  To make it do anything other than pass scalars to your function you have to use the `signature` parameter (which is both complex and slower).

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a guess, but looks like your code can be simplified to

```
data = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 1], [1, -1], [2, -1]])  # (5,2) array
th_ = np.array([[1, 1]])
th0_ = -2
alist = [signed_dist(x, th_, th0_) for x in data]
arr = np.array(alist)    # (5,?,?) array
arr = arr[:,0,0]   # (5,) array
arr[arr>0] = 1
```